# How to install TA-lib to Windows 10 machine

Tags: python, ta-lib

I have a Windows 10 64bit machine with Python 3.8.5 installed. I tried downloading ta-lib from https://mrjbq7.github.io/ta-lib/install.html and followed the instructions.

Step 1: Dependencies > Windows > downloaded the zip file.

Step 2: extracted to C:\ta-lib, as per their webpage.

Step 3: VS Code > terminal: pip install TA-Lib.

then the following error shows:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOEzm.png)

I have tried the following:

1. I had Python 3.9.6, and it failed. Read a similar problem where the solution was to get pythong 3.8 or older. So installed that and tried again and failed.
2. tried using: pip install --user TA-Lib.
3. made sure the PATH for Python is there when I reinstalled Python 3.8.5
4. also tried installing ta-lib through command-prompt

Below attachments are for truf:

[error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMWft.png)

[filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mY7TF.png)

Comment: According the `setup.py` code (https://github.com/mrjbq7/ta-lib/blob/master/setup.py#L76) that the error message refers, the script is checking existence of the `c:\ta-lib\c\lib\ta_libc_cdr.lib` file. Do you have it on your PC?

Comment: Yes thats referred to Step 2 of my post. 

But upon checking the file path it was c:\ta-lib\ta-lib\c\lib\ta_libc_cdr.lib instead of what you provided. 

So I moved the ta-lib folder one level higher and now the file path is c:\ta-lib\c\lib\ta_libc_cdr.lib and tried installoing ta-lib again. still getting an error. see attachments "error message 2" and "filepath"

Comment: That screenshot doesn't contain the real error message. Please provide further text. Will be better if you copy text and paste it to pastebin.com instead of making screenshots.

Comment: I just found a solution in youtube. turns out the TA-Lib library files, for some reason, glitches with Windows. Theres an alternate TA-Lib download from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ . Since I already installed TA-Lib, I cant reproduce that error message anymore. Thanks though for looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

So I went to youtube to follow another method:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tHCAEZzUhc

I used method 1 from the video.

method 1:  [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/)

method 2:
https://pypi.anaconda.org/masdeseiscaracteres/simple/

TA-Lib installed successfully.